# Estimating direction of travel of road line segment based on long/lat in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Well, this seems pretty simple but haven't been answered cleanly in previous relevant questions for example:

- [Identify the direction of traveling road segment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75554) and
- [Finding compass direction between two distant GPS points?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228656)

I have a large dataset of road network (`multi-linestrings`) of an area of interest converted to linestrings using `ST_Dump()`. For each `linestring`, I would like to estimate "*the direction of travel*" (north to south, east to west and vice versa) based on extracted X,Ys. Two sample linestrings are shown below.

[image: linestring 1]

[image: linestring 2]

For the above sample linestrings, `ST_StartPoint()` and `ST_EndPoint()` return the start and end points (`Xs`, `Ys`) of the same. Based on these `X`,`Ys` (long/lat), how do I estimate the direction of travel of these linestrings?

**UPDATE**

Assuming that I have my area of interest in the northern hemisphere. Following diagram may "represent" the *"direction of travel"* (from north to south).

[image: "direction of travel" in the first case]

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for ST_Azimuth

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.4/ST_Azimuth.html

Comment: Thank you for your words =) Please correct me if I am terribly wrong. ST_Azimuth(ST_StartPoint(geom), ST_EndPoint(geom)) estimates the north-based azimuth (direction) of linestring. While, I am trying to estimate whether linestring is north-to-south and vice versa etc. based on latitudes/longitudes differences. Is there something wrong with this approach?

Comment: As suggested here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75554/identify-the-direction-of-traveling-road-segment linestring's "direction of travel" can be determined by the order of coordinates as well.

Comment: I might misunderstand what you want. As I understand it toy want the direction of theline from start point to end point. That you get from ST_Azimuth, both for geometry and geography type. From that value you can tell if the direction is north or south or east or west. You can have a table with ranges defining the directions and join the answer against that if you want it expressed in text. A table with fields for min radians, max radians and text representation. Or is there a "direction of travel" based on something else than start point and end point that you are searching?

Comment: My bad! Probably, I was unable to provide better explanations. I am aware that ST_Azimuth() would return me line segment's direction in degrees or radians. Basically, this is not what I am looking for. I wanted to identify whether line segment is towards north-south (in the first case, for example) or not based on long/lat differences i.e., what is the "direction of travel" based on order/difference of coordinates of linestring. I will add one more figure to help clarify "direction of travel".

Comment: I am afraid I still miss something. From your last example, you will get approx pi as azimuth, which tells you that the direction between the 2 points is towards south. Isn't that want you want to find out?

Comment: I don't need to estimate azimuth (pi) in the moment. Based on extracted lat/long, e.g. ST_X(ST_StartPoint(geom)), ST_Y(ST_EndPoint(geom)) and their order in the linestring, I wanted to estimate direction of travelling line segment. I found another question at StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221157/distance-between-two-points-east-west-north-south This question tells the difference of distance between latitudes and longitudes. Based on a similar concept, is it possible to estimate direction of travelling line segment if I have x1,y1 and x2,y2?

Comment: you mean you want x meters south/north and y meters east/west?

Comment: ST_Distance() would do that. But, my crazy idea is... Let say if one travels from north to south then there will be a change in latitude (Y coordinates)?. I have two points x1,y1 and x2,y2. Thus, by comparing these latitudes, is it not possible to estimate whether line segment is from north to south and vice versa? I hope it is not the creepiest idea you have ever heard :)

Comment: you mean like y1>y2 going south, y2>y1 going north, yes why not

Comment: Yesss :) and similarly for the longitudes in the case of east-west and vice versa. Will this approach work for streets having azimuth 0 - 359 degrees? I showed only two sample streets having pi = 180 and 90 but in reality in my dataset there can be streets of any azimuth value. Care to add something so that I could accept it as answer?